# Query to remove continuous eligibility records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get rid of the records whose eligibility already exists in another record of the `memid`.  In the below example I need the output with only rows where I have mentioned Y. Table has `memid,effdate,termdate`.  I have just prefixed Y to mention the record I need as output. How can we do this.Thanks.

```
    MEMID     EFFDATE     TERMDATE
Y   A1      2012-01-01    2078-12-31              
    A1      2012-02-01    2078-12-31

Y   B1      2007-05-01    2008-12-31              
Y   B1      2009-10-01    2010-04-30

Y   A2      1999-01-01    2078-12-31                 
    A2      2006-01-01    2011-04-28 

    B2      1999-01-01    1999-10-01              
Y   B2      1999-01-01    2000-09-30 
Y   B2      2006-01-01    2006-01-01 
Y   B2      2009-08-01    2078-12-31 

Y   A3      2000-03-01    2009-01-31             
    A3      2002-04-01    2009-01-31 
    A3      2003-01-01    2006-06-30 
    A3      2006-01-01    2009-01-31 
Y   A3      2009-10-01    2010-07-31 
Y   A3      2011-06-01    2012-09-30 
    A3      2011-09-01    2012-09-30 
Y   A3      2013-06-01    2078-12-31 
    A3      2013-07-01    2078-12-31

    B3      1999-01-01    2008-11-30              
Y   B3      1999-01-01    2078-12-31 
    B3      2006-01-01    2008-11-30
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, it isn't clear. Is it possible to reword your example and improve the formatting?

What is your definition of "eligibility"?

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? You have tagged both. Also your example data is very neat, what happens if you have overlapping ranges, i.e. `B4, 2014-01-01, 2014-01-31` and `B4, 2014-01-15, 2014-02-28`. Your full range is `2014-01-01` to `2014-02-28`, but you need both records to get this, so you would have records that overlap if they were to both remain.

Answer (score 1):

select all ranges where there is no covering bigger range with NOT EXISTS. Then remove duplicates with DISTINCT.

```
select distinct memid, effdate, termdate
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable bigger
  where bigger.memid = mytable.memid
  and
  (
    (bigger.effdate <= mytable.effdate and bigger.termdate > mytable.termdate)
    or
    (bigger.effdate < mytable.effdate and bigger.termdate >= mytable.termdate)
  )
);
```

Comment: Nice...working....  How should i modify this query to ALSO get like.....If i also have records ex B4 2001-01-01  2001-01-31 and B4 2001-02-01  2005-12-31.  then i need output as B4 2001-01-01 2005-12-31

Comment: This is no easy task. I suggest you place a new request asking how to combine adjacent date ranges. Maybe you even find somthing on stackoverflow. With a suitable SQL statement found, you simply put above query in its from clause.

Comment: The query is not working for data C2 2000-01-01  2005-02-28 
C2 2000-05-01  2012-02-29 
C2 2006-01-01  2012-03-01 , I need output as C2  2000-01-01 2012-03-01.  How can i modify this

Comment: Same answer. Make this a new request. It is something entirely different to scan through partly overlapping time ranges and identify start and end dates from simply ignoring records containing sub time ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the [Gaps and Islands](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf) problem. Since you have tagged both MySQL and SQL-Server, and have not responded to my question asking you to clarify which, I will give a solution for both.

Your first step is expand all your ranges into continuous data by joining with a numbers table. This will turn a single row into one row for every date in the range:

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT  t.memid, Date = DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.EffDate)
FROM    YourTable t
        INNER JOIN Numbers n
            ON n.Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t.EffDate, t.TermDate);
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT  t.memid, DATE_ADD(t.EffDate, INTERVAL n.Number DAY) AS Date
FROM    YourTable t
        INNER JOIN Numbers n
            ON n.Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(t.EffDate, t.TermDate);
```

This will turn this row:

```
memid   EFFDATE     TERMDATE
A3      2009-10-01  2009-10-05
```

Into

```
memid   Date        
A3      2009-10-01  
A3      2009-10-02
A3      2009-10-03
A3      2009-10-04
A3      2009-10-05
```

If you don't have a numbers table, [then you should probably create one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506). (In each of the SQL Fiddle's below I have created a numbers table, so you can find ways of doing so there.

Now you have your continuous ranges you can apply the appropriate *gaps and islands* solution.

If you are using SQL Server then you can use ranking functions to resolve this:

```
WITH ContinuousRange AS
(   SELECT  t.memid, 
            d.Date,
            GroupingSet = DATEADD(DAY, -DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY memid 
                                                            ORDER BY d.Date), d.Date)
    FROM    T
            INNER JOIN Numbers n
                ON n.Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t.EffDate, t.TermDate)
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT Date = DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.EffDate)) d
)
SELECT  cr.MemID,
        EffDate = MIN(cr.Date),
        TermDate = MAX(cr.Date)
FROM    ContinuousRange cr
GROUP BY cr.MemID, cr.GroupingSet
ORDER BY cr.MemID, cr.GroupingSet;
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c9598/1)**

This works on the basis that end number in a sequence minus it's order in the sequence will give a constant for a continuous range, e.g.:

```
Sequence | OrderInSequence | (Sequence - OrderInSequence)
---------+-----------------+------------------------------
    1    |      1          |            0
    2    |      2          |            0
    3    |      3          |            0
    5    |      4          |            1
    6    |      5          |            1
```

As you can see, where there is a gap in the sequence (between 3 and 5) the value in the 3rd column changes, this is how the column `GroupingSet` is calculated:

```
GroupingSet = DATEADD(DAY, -DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY memid ORDER BY d.Date), d.Date)
```

Then when you can use thisc column to get the minimum and maximum value of each consectutive sequence (or island).

Since MySQL does not have ranking functions you will need to use user defined variables to emulate them:

```
SELECT  MemID, 
        MIN(Date) AS EffDate,
        MAX(Date) AS TermDate
FROM    (   SELECT  t.memid, 
                    @i:= CASE WHEN t.MemID = @m 
                                AND DATE_ADD(t.EffDate, INTERVAL n.Number DAY) 
                                        <= DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                            THEN @i
                            ELSE @i + 1
                        END AS GroupingSet,
                    @m:= t.memid,
                    @d:= DATE_ADD(t.EffDate, INTERVAL n.Number DAY) AS Date
            FROM    t
                    INNER JOIN Numbers n
                        ON n.Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(t.TermDate, t.EffDate)
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @M:= '', @i:= 0, @d:= NULL) i
            ORDER BY t.memid, DATE_ADD(t.EffDate, INTERVAL n.Number DAY)
        ) t
GROUP BY MemID, GroupingSet;
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eb4d/23)**

Getting the Grouping Set here is a more iterative process. The data is ordered by MemID and the date, then at each row the value of the date and the memid is stored in the variables @d and @m respectively. If the memid in the new row is the same as @m (i.e still in the same group of memid's) and the date in the new row is 1 day ahead of, or the same as @d then the grouping set does not increment, if it is a new memid, or the date is further than 1 day ahead of the previous date, then it is a new 'island' and the grouping set increments.

---

**EDIT**

To help with memory issues then you can deal with different scenarios differently. The first step is to remove any records contained entirely within another, e.g.

```
MemID   EffDate     TermDate
A1      2012-01-01  2078-12-31
A1      2012-02-01  2078-12-31
```

With these two, the second row is not required since its date range is contained entirely within the first. So this can be removed (This is done in the CTE called *Filtered* in the below query).

The second way to help is to remove the range expansion where it is not required, so with the above example we are just left with:

```
MemID   EffDate     TermDate
A1      2012-01-01  2078-12-31
```

And this is the only row for `A1`, it is therefore not necessary to expand this out into all the days between the EffDate and TermDate, and then take a minimum and maximum, we can simply use the EffDate and TermDate as they are. This is the query below the UNION ALL in the query below.

```
WITH Filtered AS
(   SELECT  MemID, EffDate, TermDate
    FROM    T
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    T T2
                WHERE   T.MemID = T2.MemID
                AND     T2.EffDate < T.EffDate
                AND     T2.TermDate >= T.TermDate
            )
), ContinuousRange AS
(   SELECT  t.memid, 
            d.Date,
            GroupingSet = DATEADD(DAY, -DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY memid 
                                                            ORDER BY d.Date), d.Date)
    FROM    Filtered T
            INNER JOIN Numbers n
                ON n.Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t.EffDate, t.TermDate)
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT Date = DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, t.EffDate)) d
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    Filtered T2
                WHERE   T.MemID = T2.MemID
                AND (   (T2.EffDate > T.EffDate AND T2.EffDate < T.TermDate)
                    OR  (T2.TermDate > T.EffDate AND T2.TermDate < T.TermDate)
                    )
            )
)
SELECT  cr.MemID,
        EffDate = MIN(cr.Date),
        TermDate = MAX(cr.Date), 1
FROM    ContinuousRange cr
GROUP BY cr.MemID, cr.GroupingSet
UNION ALL
SELECT  T.MemID, T.EffDate, T.TermDate, 0
FROM    Filtered T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Filtered T2
            WHERE   T.MemID = T2.MemID
            AND (   (T2.EffDate > T.EffDate AND T2.EffDate < T.TermDate)
                OR  (T2.TermDate > T.EffDate AND T2.TermDate < T.TermDate)
                )
        )
ORDER BY MemID, EffDate;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baf4f/4)**

Comment: Sorry, its a sql server. Is there a better way?..... I am getting the error  "Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140750153187328' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
".

Comment: I have amended the query to use less space in the sort operation.